# Clean columns that contain lists as variables which are empty/NULL/NA in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

Given the following dataframe with lists as values:

```
df <- structure(list(keys.userId = c("9875", "5465", 
"1234", "4567", "8910"), user_data.SSIDs = list(
    c("qjJf5iZtYboSPvqe1oa/xg==", "ul7kroLEB2cZx6AMGhjnrA==", 
    "OYRT/hYu1Dl3/S5WIWyLHA==", "HFiSH/Tu0RSaQgIbDEZfeA==", "gUBxBfxjGdyPNzqYX7t6nA==", 
    "m7UqzqaXUm1GkXMbxf+SJw==", "KjxvZwsVCNSTtXXKiidmjw==", "3UOqe+4qPVZYXvja8GBEqg==", 
    "a9Ba8b19tY/bprM7WA326A==", "uStr9Fg+JlU9B+hdBCafZg==", "i9J11W00HFmoeCDObOfSdA==", 
    "A9vOz8zSrwDiQcKv8hk64Q==", "/8QeMoqFwd/eJ+/6NKk1iQ==", "HbyJqQxUfH6oiW3skqPzGQ==", 
    "51H9RcZmdRgkgg4X6U/mhQ==", "dwat86ppe1b/WXSaGi8r3w==", "yBCbMedxtZdiGFXmTfk2eQ==", 
    "wKSIsw3sDPRQhLIhdQkBJw==", "3LkFUenHOXWL4Be5T4XmaQ==", "Krni6eGQUnZuL/jU0MzKNA==", 
    "Wt9BCH4guyC4oSIHwE8XGA==", "rbgxp/3YPdHiownOdZHf+A==", "34rmNRgT/xFDXIDwHKIY6Q==", 
    "pT3zFcGdlJKmR+khJLMoVw==", "eni3X9I2B4KRK+sho2MbjA==", "sxuba/1Brg4CrYL8AFv8ZQ==", 
    "EYIxPOXPVvop99YD0vjXPA==", "JC1xqrtmQEaohwzviYDFYA==", "qv+cfEEqsIGrDFuEqpkQuw==", 
    "d3xXMR1RDKZdrDwQd97kNQ==", "qU1JULumBTqw+m/rLr4E7A==", "teDCJvNdyjktWD6leDpCmw==", 
    "ytSBHvzbEACq56aEHZlXEw==", "eV7WGimPD01weRI19ojO3g==", "vNkJyD9KOzOprGkYyfViMA==", 
    "r8jjZXWyax7JPfJUPFwRTQ==", "rJ1N3ONwDBK+jwFf+7xeHg==", "2xPbTqIww1KI/tVL2UH1cw==", 
    "1hk1AOU4DZXV52Auyr2FHA==", "aNH8uS5nrlwcHb8rLdZeXQ==", "5JPQs2z4N1Dru0dGI9ImBQ==", 
    "nbQIn5G4uyl8b1+A6aVkQg==", "A/UcwEccakKDuiATgoP1NA==", "JC57Ib2V7fOU/CgBk2R41g==", 
    "PsI8Ys++JveA+SuafbB8pg==", "eXiuBymYN+tcbjtpM9Vxmg==", "jEdP3Rs02d/4UE8G1GeE3A=="
    ), NULL, c("qjJf5iZtYboSPvqe1oa/xg==", "ul7kroLEB2cZx6AMGhjnrA==", 
    "OYRT/hYu1Dl3/S5WIWyLHA==", "HFiSH/Tu0RSaQgIbDEZfeA==", "gUBxBfxjGdyPNzqYX7t6nA==", 
    "m7UqzqaXUm1GkXMbxf+SJw==", "KjxvZwsVCNSTtXXKiidmjw==", "3UOqe+4qPVZYXvja8GBEqg==", 
    "a9Ba8b19tY/bprM7WA326A==", "uStr9Fg+JlU9B+hdBCafZg==", "i9J11W00HFmoeCDObOfSdA==", 
    "A9vOz8zSrwDiQcKv8hk64Q==", "/8QeMoqFwd/eJ+/6NKk1iQ==", "HbyJqQxUfH6oiW3skqPzGQ==", 
    "51H9RcZmdRgkgg4X6U/mhQ==", "dwat86ppe1b/WXSaGi8r3w==", "yBCbMedxtZdiGFXmTfk2eQ==", 
    "wKSIsw3sDPRQhLIhdQkBJw==", "3LkFUenHOXWL4Be5T4XmaQ==", "Krni6eGQUnZuL/jU0MzKNA==", 
    "Wt9BCH4guyC4oSIHwE8XGA==", "rbgxp/3YPdHiownOdZHf+A==", "34rmNRgT/xFDXIDwHKIY6Q==", 
    "pT3zFcGdlJKmR+khJLMoVw==", "eni3X9I2B4KRK+sho2MbjA==", "sxuba/1Brg4CrYL8AFv8ZQ==", 
    "EYIxPOXPVvop99YD0vjXPA==", "JC1xqrtmQEaohwzviYDFYA==", "qv+cfEEqsIGrDFuEqpkQuw==", 
    "d3xXMR1RDKZdrDwQd97kNQ==", "qU1JULumBTqw+m/rLr4E7A==", "teDCJvNdyjktWD6leDpCmw==", 
    "ytSBHvzbEACq56aEHZlXEw==", "eV7WGimPD01weRI19ojO3g==", "vNkJyD9KOzOprGkYyfViMA==", 
    "r8jjZXWyax7JPfJUPFwRTQ==", "rJ1N3ONwDBK+jwFf+7xeHg==", "2xPbTqIww1KI/tVL2UH1cw==", 
    "1hk1AOU4DZXV52Auyr2FHA==", "aNH8uS5nrlwcHb8rLdZeXQ==", "5JPQs2z4N1Dru0dGI9ImBQ==", 
    "nbQIn5G4uyl8b1+A6aVkQg==", "A/UcwEccakKDuiATgoP1NA==", "JC57Ib2V7fOU/CgBk2R41g==", 
    "PsI8Ys++JveA+SuafbB8pg==", "eXiuBymYN+tcbjtpM9Vxmg==", "jEdP3Rs02d/4UE8G1GeE3A=="
    ), NULL, c("qjJf5iZtYboSPvqe1oa/xg==", "ul7kroLEB2cZx6AMGhjnrA==", 
    "OYRT/hYu1Dl3/S5WIWyLHA==", "HFiSH/Tu0RSaQgIbDEZfeA==", "gUBxBfxjGdyPNzqYX7t6nA==", 
    "m7UqzqaXUm1GkXMbxf+SJw==", "KjxvZwsVCNSTtXXKiidmjw==", "3UOqe+4qPVZYXvja8GBEqg==", 
    "a9Ba8b19tY/bprM7WA326A==", "uStr9Fg+JlU9B+hdBCafZg==", "i9J11W00HFmoeCDObOfSdA==", 
    "A9vOz8zSrwDiQcKv8hk64Q==", "/8QeMoqFwd/eJ+/6NKk1iQ==", "HbyJqQxUfH6oiW3skqPzGQ==", 
    "51H9RcZmdRgkgg4X6U/mhQ==", "dwat86ppe1b/WXSaGi8r3w==", "yBCbMedxtZdiGFXmTfk2eQ==", 
    "wKSIsw3sDPRQhLIhdQkBJw==", "3LkFUenHOXWL4Be5T4XmaQ==", "Krni6eGQUnZuL/jU0MzKNA==", 
    "Wt9BCH4guyC4oSIHwE8XGA==", "rbgxp/3YPdHiownOdZHf+A==", "34rmNRgT/xFDXIDwHKIY6Q==", 
    "pT3zFcGdlJKmR+khJLMoVw==", "eni3X9I2B4KRK+sho2MbjA==", "sxuba/1Brg4CrYL8AFv8ZQ==", 
    "EYIxPOXPVvop99YD0vjXPA==", "JC1xqrtmQEaohwzviYDFYA==", "qv+cfEEqsIGrDFuEqpkQuw==", 
    "d3xXMR1RDKZdrDwQd97kNQ==", "qU1JULumBTqw+m/rLr4E7A==", "teDCJvNdyjktWD6leDpCmw==", 
    "ytSBHvzbEACq56aEHZlXEw==", "eV7WGimPD01weRI19ojO3g==", "vNkJyD9KOzOprGkYyfViMA==", 
    "r8jjZXWyax7JPfJUPFwRTQ==", "rJ1N3ONwDBK+jwFf+7xeHg==", "2xPbTqIww1KI/tVL2UH1cw==", 
    "1hk1AOU4DZXV52Auyr2FHA==", "aNH8uS5nrlwcHb8rLdZeXQ==", "5JPQs2z4N1Dru0dGI9ImBQ==", 
    "nbQIn5G4uyl8b1+A6aVkQg==", "A/UcwEccakKDuiATgoP1NA==", "JC57Ib2V7fOU/CgBk2R41g==", 
    "PsI8Ys++JveA+SuafbB8pg==", "eXiuBymYN+tcbjtpM9Vxmg==", "jEdP3Rs02d/4UE8G1GeE3A=="
    )), user_data.contacts = list(list(), NULL, list(), NULL, 
    list())), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to perform Jaccard calculation using:

```
jaccard <- function(vector1, vector2) {

  return(length(intersect(vector1, vector2)) / 
           length(union(vector1, vector2)))

}

jaccardV <- Vectorize(jaccard)
```

and I want to clean the data a bit.

I am trying to clean the NULL/NA/0 length lists rows.

Please advise what is the right way to do this, the first thing I thought about was:

```
df %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(isNull = ifelse(is.null(unlist(user_data.contacts)), TRUE, FALSE))
```

But it returns False everywhere.

Is there any way to do it right and efficient? Please advise.

Finally after cleaning I will run:

```
df %>% 
  cleaning %>%
dplyr::mutate(contacts_jaccard = jaccardV(user_data.contacts, lag(user_data.contacts)))
```

Comment: Do you want to remove the NULL columns? Or do you want to replace the NULL values with something else?

Comment: @HarroCyranka as I have stated above, each column have list(NULL), list(0), list(NA)'s, I want to remove these rows.
pull function return an error Error in UseMethod("pull") : 
  no applicable method for 'pull' applied to an object of class "list"

Comment: @HarroCyranka PERFECTO! So sapply just took the each element of the column user_data.contacts (= a list) and for each element for this list it returned TRUE/FALSE so if I have NA/NULL as part of the inner list I should think about the logic to ignore them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a way to do it:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
  filter(!map_lgl(user_data.contacts, is.null)) %>% 
  filter(!map_lgl(user_data.contacts, function(x) length(x) == 0)) %>% 
  filter(!map_lgl(user_data.contacts, is.na)) %>% 
  mutate(contacts_jaccard = jaccardV(user_data.contacts, lag(user_data.contacts)))
```

This doens't produce any output since in the mock data you provided all rows are removed now. It is not necessary to make a new column `isNull` if the only purpose is to remove rows later on. I started to prefer `map` over `sapply` as it is really easy to force a certain result. In this case, `map_lgl` will only produce TRUE/FALSE outcomes.

Note, that if one element of the list column is longer than 1, you should use this instead:

```
df %>% 
  filter(!map_lgl(user_data.contacts, is.null)) %>% 
  filter(!map_lgl(user_data.contacts, function(x) length(x) == 0)) %>% 
  filter(!map_lgl(user_data.contacts, function(x) is.na(x)[1])) %>% 
  mutate(contacts_jaccard = jaccardV(user_data.contacts, lag(user_data.contacts)))
```

Comment: I think your answer is the most deep and strict. You've taken into account the length of the list with NULL/NA/0's

Comment: Please explain the ```filter(!map_lgl(user_data.contacts, function(x) (length(x) == 0)[1]))```
@jbgruber

Comment: What part of it? The difference to the first one is that if one row has more than one entry, only the first will be used. This is necessary as the produced vector is too long otherwise and filter will fail. You could try it without the filter on this: `user_data.contacts <- list(list(), list(NA), NULL, list(NULL, 2, 3, 4))`

Comment: But why do you ask for the first one? I have run it with 
```map_lgl(user_data.contacts, function(x) (length(x) == 0))```
where ```user_data.contacts <- list(list(), list(NA), NULL, list(NULL, 2, 3, 4))``` @jbgruber

Comment: You are totally right, only the `is.na` filter can't deal with longer entries. Not quite sure why this is the case...

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work for you. Go through the contacts column, create a new column that tells if it is null or not and then filter them out based on a new column

```
library(tidyverse)

new_df <- df %>%as_tibble() %>%
    mutate(is_Null = sapply(user_data.contacts, is_null)) %>%
    filter(is_Null == FALSE)

new_df
```

Comment: `is_Null == FALSE` is a bit clunky. You can accomplish the same with `!is_Null`.

Comment: PERFECTO! So sapply just took the each element of the column user_data.contacts (= a list) and for each element for this list it returned TRUE/FALSE so if I have NA/NULL as part of the inner list I should think about the logic to ignore them.

Comment: I will alter my response to deal with na values

Answer (score 1):

The column `user_data.contacts` is a list, when you mutate that column it treats it as one list. Try grouping your data `rowwise` before `mutate`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(isNull = is.null(unlist(user_data.contacts)))


# A tibble: 5 x 4 # added data to 1st observation for test
  keys.userId user_data.SSIDs user_data.contacts isNull
  <chr>       <list>          <list>             <lgl> 
1 9875        <chr [47]>      <list [3]>         FALSE 
2 5465        <NULL>          <NULL>             TRUE  
3 1234        <chr [47]>      <list [0]>         TRUE  
4 4567        <NULL>          <NULL>             TRUE  
5 8910        <chr [47]>      <list [0]>         TRUE
```

Comment: `ifelse()` AND `TRUE`, `FALSE` is redundant. You can just use `is.null` on its own. Also, `unlist` won't work if there are is than one entry in one row of the list.

Comment: I was simply giving OP a way forward. You are right about the `ifelse()` simply `is.null(unlist(user_data.contacts))` would suffice. I'm not sure what your statement on `unlist` is saying.